# Search in HTML page using Regex patterns with python

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing, html-parsing

I'm trying to find a string inside a HTML page with known patterns.
for example, in the following HTML code:

```
<TABLE WIDTH="100%">
<TR><TD ALIGN="LEFT" width="50%">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=BOTTOM WIDTH=50%><FONT SIZE=-1>( <STRONG>1</STRONG></FONT> <FONT SIZE=-2>of</FONT> <STRONG><FONT SIZE=-1>1</STRONG> )</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>
<HR>
<TABLE WIDTH="100%">
<TR>    <TD ALIGN="LEFT" WIDTH="50%"><B>String 1</B></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="RIGHT" WIDTH="50%"><B><A Name=h1 HREF=#h0></A><A  HREF=#h2></A><B><I></I></B>String</B></TD>
</TR>
<TR><TD ALIGN="LEFT" WIDTH="50%"><b>String 2.</B>
</TD>
<TD ALIGN="RIGHT" WIDTH="50%"> <B>
String 3
</B></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<HR>
<font size="+1">String 4</font><BR>
...
```

I want to find **String 4** , and I know that it will always be between

`<HR><font size="+1">`
   and    `</font><BR>`

how can I search for the string using RE?

edit:

I've tried the following, but no success:

```
p = re.match('<HR><font size="+1">(.*?)</font><BR>',html)
```

thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using xpath instead of regex?

Comment: I've tried using BeautifulSoup. It didn't work because I'm running the parser on multiple pages and there are slight changes between them.

Comment: @Rgo: XPath queries (with lxml) can take care of pages with slight differences.

Comment: Your try with re.match did not work because re.match tries to match from the beginning. Also the `+` has special meaning so should be escaped. But you were on the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
re.findall(r'<HR>\s*<font size="\+1">(.*?)</font><BR>', html, re.DOTALL)
```

`findall` is returning a list with everything that is captured between the brackets in the regular expression. I used re.DOTALL so the dot also captures end of lines.

I used `\s*` because I was not sure whether there would be any whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

This works, but may not be very robust:

```
import re
r = re.compile('<HR>\s?<font size="\+1">(.+?)</font>\s?<BR>', re.IGNORECASE)
r.findall(html)
```

You will be better off using a proper HTML parser.  BeautifulSoup is excellent and easy to use.  Look it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r'<HR>\n<font size="\+1">([^<]*)<\/font><BR>', html, re.MULTILINE)
```