# Extract text from CSS based on font-size

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a function that parses all headers based on header's tags (h1/2...). Now I want to expand on it and add a feature that parses text based on font-size - say either 20px or 1.5em, regardless of the headers. I want a feature that brings any text written in font-size greater than X, wherever it is on the page. The function takes json file as an input, composed of a random HTML (and whatever website could have, i.e. CSS etc) in it.

Based on [crummy](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/download/2.x/documentation.html)  it seems like one possible option is to use soup.fetch(), however, I haven't found many examples using it for this purpose.

Since font-size well might appear under CSS component I'm not sure that `bs4` is the right package for it. I assume the answer includes `cssutils` or `tinycss` but haven't been able to find the best way to use those for this task.

As a reference - My code for header's tags was posted for a review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166671/extract-html-content-based-on-tags-specifically-headers/166674?noredirect=1#comment317280_166674.

Posts I've checked:
[What is the pythonic way to implement a css parser/replacer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592347/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-implement-a-css-parser-replacer)  ;
[Find all the span styles with font size larger than the most common one via beautiful soup python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843353/find-all-the-span-styles-with-font-size-larger-than-the-most-common-one-via-beau)    ;
[Search in HTML page using Regex patterns with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294019/search-in-html-page-using-regex-patterns-with-python)  ;
[How to parse a web page containing CSS and HTML using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458788/how-to-parse-a-web-page-containing-css-and-html-using-python)     ;
[how to extract text within font tag using beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854128/how-to-extract-text-within-font-tag-using-beautifulsoup)  ;
[Extract text with bold content from css selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389153/extract-text-with-bold-content-from-css-selector)

Thanks much,

Comment: How does it parse the text based on the font size? Do you mean that you know which header tag has what font size?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MoonCheesez . I mean regardless of the headers, I want a feature that brings any text written in font-size greater than X. I'll edit for clarity - thanks.